# How to use addChild() without images in Swift

Tags: swift, addchild

I want to add a node in a game, but I want to use it without images, but with drawing code. Can anyone give me a hint? I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A node is not a UIView; it has no `drawRect:` and no graphics context. You can use the usual `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext...` dance to create a UIImage in code and use that image as the node's texture.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how can I add an image (drawer with code)?

Comment: I don't understand those words, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, kinda new un programming. To be honest I don't even know what I don't know.

Comment: My explanation of how to draw in code in iOS might help you: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_graphics_contexts